# How can I help my dog adjust to a move?

Tags: dogs, house-moving

One of my two dogs (about a year old) is having trouble adjusting to a recent move to a new state.  He is fretful and nervous.  What can I do to help his anxiety?

Comment: What he does exactly? In what kind of situation are you keeping them?

Comment: long walks; let him know the environment

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to answer as the question is quite broad, but I would have a few advices:

- Check with your vet that there is no real "medical" problem with your dog linked to his new condition
- A pheromone diffuser could help the dog relax during the day, and in particular help him relieve his anxiety before/when sleeping. The technical term is [Dog appeasing pheromone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_appeasing_pheromone) , your vet could advice you on that
- Help your dog adjust to his new life by keeping a strict schedule, at least temporarily, for the meals, walks, sleeping time, playing time, etc.